# Mockito: default return value

Tags: java, android, mockito

According to the [documentation](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html), non stubbed methods return null.
I want to test a method that should return "null" under some circumstances, however the test fails with the exception indicating the method was not called.

This is the test init function:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mDataEntry = getFakeEntry();
    when(mRepository.getEntry(1L)).thenReturn(mDataEntry);
    mGetEntry = new GetEntryImpl(mRepository);
}
```

and this is the failed test:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testGetEntry_failure() throws Exception {
    mGetEntry.execute(2L, mCallback);
    verify(mRepository).getEntry(eq(2L));
    verify(mCallback).onError(anyString(), Mockito.any(Exception.class));
}
```

the execute method calls the mocked object mRepository function getEntry(2L) which I was expecting to return null. However, this is what Mockito tells me when I run the test:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mRepository.getEntry(2);
-> at com.xyz.interactor.GetEntryTest.testGetEntry_failure(GetEntryTest.java:54)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I tried adding

```
when(mRepository.getEntry(2L)).thenReturn(null);
```

to the init function, but it makes no difference. If I return a valid object instead of null, then the test fails as expected, because the onError function is not called (so the mocked object's function for value 2L is being called when I specify a valid return value).

How can I have the mocked object return null for a set of values?

Edit:

here's the code for the function under test:

```
@Override
public void execute(final long id, final Callback<DataEntry> callback)  {
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DataEntry dataEntry = mDataEntryRepository.getEntry(id);
            if (dataEntry != null) {
                callback.onResult(dataEntry);
            } else {
                callback.onError("TODO", null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and for reference, the success test works:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public void testGetEntry_success() throws Exception {
    mGetEntry.execute(1L, mCallback);
    verify(mRepository).getEntry(eq(1L));
    verify(mCallback).onResult(eq(mDataEntry));
}
```

Comment: You can't make a method return null if it is never called.  The question you  should be asking yourself is why `execute()` does not call `getEntry()` or any other method of `mRepository` during the test. You have not posted the code for `execute()`, so no one here knows the answer.

Comment: The method gets called if I mock the value for 2L by returning a valid object, so it's not a matter of why it's not being called.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with Mockito default values / returning null.

I wrote a modified SSCCE, and the tests run fine for me.  I don't have the android API, so I couldn't use the AsynchTask.execute().  From what I understand, this code would run in a separate thread, so you might not be guaranteed that the code was run before verify is called.  If you take out the AsynchTask and implement execute as follows, does it still fail?  Is it possible for an exception to be thrown in execute?

```
    public void execute( final long id, final Callback<DataEntry> callback)  {
        DataEntry dataEntry = mDataEntryRepository.getEntry(id);
        if (dataEntry != null) {
            callback.onResult(dataEntry);
        } else {
            callback.onError("TODO", null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The test runs without the AsyncTask (which effectively runs the code on a separate thread to make the synchronous call into the repository into an asynchronous one). However, the success test is using the same API and it works, so why does it not work for the failure test? As I stated above, if I mock the repository to return an object for value 2L, then the test calls into the repository and fails because onError is not called (as expected), so it seems that not defining a return value for 2L is somewhat related to the problem.

Comment: Are you able to debug it?  My two best guesses are asserting on a the wrong instance ( considering you got the output "Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock." )  or that it's really not being called ( due to a bug or exception ).  It passes for my SSCCE.

Comment: The return value of mRepository.getEntry(2) isn't the problem if, as stated in the error that "mRepository.getEntry(2);" isn't called.

Comment: I can debug, and I see it getting to the execute method in the interactor However, a breakpoint set on the line "DataEntry dataEntry = mDataEntryRepository.getEntry(id);" breaks and immediately stops the debugger, I can't step past that point.